# Where does the formula for the particular solution to an non-homogenous ODE $y'' + y' + y = f $ come from

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

We have learnt to solve non-homogenous ODE's of the form $y'' + y' + y = f(t)$
in first calculating the homogenous solution (using matrixes and eigenvalues), then adding the particular solution, like:
$ y = y_h + y_p $

The $y_h$ has the form $y_h=c_1 e^{\lambda_1} + c_2 e^{\lambda_2}$ (or even longer)

So far, so good. Now, the formula we got for the particular solution is as following:

$ y_p = y_2 \int{\frac{y_1 f}{y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2}} dt - y_1 \int{\frac{y_2 f}{y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2}} dt$

The formula came just without any explaination, so I have two question:

1. Where does this formula come from?
2. How do I apply when I have more than 2 solutions (more than 2 eigenvalues of the matrix)

Comment: See [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)